# How can I prompt SQL server to use more suitable index in query?

Tags: execution-plan, azure-sql-database

I have a query that somtimes runs longer than the application calling it allows. I've traced it down a clustered index seek on rather larger table. I've created a new index, that better supports this query, and it works great (one to one comparisons with hints to change index used).

Problem is that when the application executes the query, SQL server is still using executing plans with the (slow) clustered index. It doesn't do this when I execute the exact same code in Management Studio.

How can I get SQL server to use the better index? The query is generated by a third party component, so index hints are **not** an option. There is no forced execution plan for this query

@@version gives me "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8", if that matters.

Following comments, I've tried my hand at a plan guide. From "Tracked Queries" I get the query in question on the form "())"

```
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide   
@name = N'Guide1',   
@stmt = N'<query>',
@type = N'SQL',  
@module_or_batch = NULL,   
@params = N'<parameterlist>',   
@hints = N'OPTION (TABLE HINT(<mytable>, INDEX (myindex)))';
```

But to no avail. It's still using the same old execution plan.

Comment: I'm surprised if you are getting a clustered index **seek** operation, that you were able to find a nonclustered index significantly more performant than that worthy of asking this question, but it's not impossible. In any case, the only way to be able to help you is if you update your post and provide your actual execution plans of both the slow and fast query (which you can upload to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)), the query, the index definitions of the clustered index and your new index, and the table definitions of the tables involved would be helpful too.

Comment: We have announced a feature to allow you to add query hints in query store (but I don't think it is quite out in production in SQL Azure yet).  So, if the text of the query is known, you can find the entry in the query store and add a hint once it ships.  Until then, you can do similar with a plan guide (but it is a bit harder to use).  It could also be that you are seeing slightly different queries, so please check whether you are using the same set options and EXACTLY the same text in both cases you describe here in SSMS vs. app

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT Plan guides seems to be what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @J.D. The clustered index is based on colA, colB, colC, colD. In this context, colC is irrelevant, and colB is a constant. My new index is colB, colA, include colC.

Comment: If your query's predicate filters on both `colA` and `colB` then theoretically your new index shouldn't be much different than the clustered index. But hard to say with you providing the **actual execution plan** as I originally suggested. Please add this and any updates / answers to questions requesting information, to your original post for further help.

Comment: Forcing plans with Query Store is newer and easier than using plan guides.  Instead of creating a plan guide use sp_query_store_force_plan. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have you checked that the query doesn't have a forced plan in Query Store? someone might have forced the wrong query

Answer (score 1):

I wolud suggest you to try this:

- identify why sql server is using the wrong index; maybe there is something to fix instead of forcing a plan
- if it is not possible you could force the query plan through the query store with `sp_query_store_force_plan`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15